# Facebook Login JS vs PHP SDK and how to keep track of users locally

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, authentication

A very simple question which I've seen kinda answers to.

1. Can you do a facebook login with PHP to authenticate a user and grab information?
2. Why then is there a JS version?

I just don't understand the difference between the two above options.

1. My web app will need to gleen the users email address as there will be a mailing list component to signing up for our service.

How do you manage this local information and uniquely identify the user each time they log in from facebook? Do you store their facebook ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- Yes - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
2- So you can do it on the client side.

You can get user's email address if you have appropriate permissions.
Yes you store their facebook id and associate users with it.

Comment: So I just don't understand how to send someone to facebook connect and return with the correct information to be logged into my app with all serverside code and no JS in the front.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/

Answer (score 0):

They both do the same thing, just on different sides: on the server or on the client.

If your authentication process relies heavily on server interaction and you have your server side code ready, use the PHP SDK. It provids you with methods to get the ID from the user. This will be unique so you can store them.

If you want to manage an application flow, say the user needs to give your website certain permissions in order to view something, it can be easy done with the Javascript SDK.